# Formatting A Published At Date

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, laravel, php-carbon

I am using Laravel for my application and I'm trying to format a published_at field after it is pulled from my database table.

When it is pulled from the database table it appears like this: 2016-10-08 19:59:22

I have a text field that uses bootstrap's datepicker and when it adds a value it puts it in this form: 11/03/2016

So I'm trying to figure out how only in this use of the edit field of the form I can format it to appear in the form of 11/03/2016. I have other places that use the field and want to keep it the way it is presented in their form and just want it formatted in this form.

In my controller edit method I am doing this.

```
$newsArticle->published_at = \Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('m / d / Y', $newsArticle->published_at)->toDateTimeString();
```

However that is giving me an error of this.

The separation symbol could not be found
Unexpected data found.
Trailing data

Answer (score 0):

`createFromFormat` method requires the first parameter to be the format of the time you are passing in the second parameter. Since you are passing `2016-10-08 19:59:22` which is in **Year-Month-Day Hour:Minute:Second** format, change the format so it becomes:

`Y-d-m H:m:s`:

`$newsArticle->published_at = \Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-d-m H:m:s', $newsArticle->published_at)->toDateTimeString();`

This should fix it.

Comment: I need it to appear as 11/03/2016 when it loads the page though.

Comment: Can you **dd** the value of **$newsArticle->published_at** and print here?

Comment: I explain what it is at the top of the post.

Comment: I've read the explanation but I need you to print the value as I asked so I can help...

Comment: Carbon {#1275 ▼
  +"date": "2016-12-18 00:00:00.000000"
  +"timezone_type": 3
  +"timezone": "UTC"
}

Comment: Another thing I need to consider is though if I try and edit a news article that hasn't been published yet it will appear NULL.

Comment: As you can see, the **date** is: `+"date": "2016-12-18 00:00:00.000000"`. So, if you can change the formatting to `Y-d-m H:m:s` instead of `m / d / Y` it will fix it. Try it.

Comment: What do you suggest I do in the event I'm trying to edit a news article that doesn't have a published_at date yet.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125247/discussion-between-user3732216-and-bytesarelife).

Comment: In case `published_at` is not present, simply create the field as: `$article->published_at = \Carbon\Carbon::now()` or simply set it to `NULL` because editing an article is not the same as publishing it and presumably you won't want that. Pretty straight forward fix but be careful.